# Why do Shap values get worse for some features as background data gets larger?

Tags: python, shapley-value

I'm trying to wrap my head around how the `shap` package in Python works. I'm experimenting with `shap` by calculating shap values for a linear model since, from what I understand, one can calculate the true shap value $\phi_{ij}$ for the $i^{th}$ observation of the $j^{th}$ feature, $x_{ij}$, as follows:

$\phi_{ij} = \hat{\beta}_j(x_{ij}-\boldsymbol{\mathrm{E}}(x_{j}))$,

where $\hat{\beta}_j$ is the OLS coefficient estimate.

I wrote a script that calculates two sets of Shapley values for a subset of the California housing data:

- **First set of shap values**: Pass the first 100 train observations into explainer ("s100")
- **Second set of shap values**: Pass all train observations into explainer ("sAll")

In both cases, I then compute the Shapley value for each feature of the 190$^{\mathrm{th}}$ observation.

Here's the result:

[image]

As you can see, the absolute difference in the estimated shap value and the true shap value grows larger for 5 of the 8 features (highlighted in red) when I feed the full train dataset into the explainer.

**My question is:** why? This result puzzles me because (as far as I can tell) the first set of Shapley values don't "see" the 190$^{\mathrm{th}}$ observation (because I only pass the first 100 train observations into the explainer), whereas the second set of Shapley values do "see" the 190$^{\mathrm{th}}$  observation, so my intuition is that they should be better able to approximate $\phi_{190,j}$.

Here's the code I used to generate the output:

```
import pandas as pd
import shap
import sklearn
import numpy as np

def get_shap_values(X,model,nsamples):    
    Xsample = X.iloc[0:nsamples,:] # Create data for background distribution
    explainer = shap.explainers.Exact(model.predict, Xsample) # Build explainer
    shap_values = explainer(X) # Compute shap values on test data (in-sample train data in this case)
    return(shap_values)

def create_shap_comparison_df(X,model,sample_ind,shap_values):
    # Create OLS results data frame
    features_list = list(X.columns) #+['Intercept']
    coef_list = list(model.coef_) #+[model.intercept_]
    features_mean_list = list(X.mean(axis=0).values)
    features_ith_obs_list = list(X.iloc[sample_ind,:].values)
    shap_value_true = np.array(coef_list)*(np.array(features_ith_obs_list)-np.array(features_mean_list))
    shap_value_python_list = list(shap_values[sample_ind:sample_ind+1,:].values[0])
    results_df = pd.DataFrame([features_list,coef_list, features_mean_list, features_ith_obs_list,shap_value_true, shap_value_python_list]).T
    results_df.columns = ['feature','coef', 'features_mean','feature_ith_value','shap_value_true','shap_value_python']
    results_df.loc[:,'shap_value_abs_diff'] = abs(results_df.shap_value_true-results_df.shap_value_python)
    return(results_df)

###############
# Main Script #
###############

print(pd.__version__) # 1.4.2
print(shap.__version__) # 0.42.0
print(sklearn.__version__) # 1.0.2
print(np.__version__) # 1.21.5

# Read data
Xtrain,ytrain = shap.datasets.california(n_points=200)
Xtrain.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)

# Fit linear model by OLS
model_ols = sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression()
model_ols.fit(Xtrain, ytrain)

shap_value_s100 = get_shap_values(Xtrain,model_ols,100) # Get shap values when using 100 samples
shap_value_sAll = get_shap_values(Xtrain,model_ols,Xtrain.shape[0]) # Get shap values when using full sample

sample_index = 190 # Sample to predict on (not "seen" by shap_value_s100, but "seen" by shap_value_sAll)
results_s100_df = create_shap_comparison_df(Xtrain,model_ols,sample_index,shap_value_s100)
results_sAll_df = create_shap_comparison_df(Xtrain,model_ols,sample_index,shap_value_sAll)

results_merged_df = pd.merge(results_s100_df,results_sAll_df.loc[:,['feature','shap_value_python','shap_value_abs_diff']],on=['feature'],suffixes=['_s100','_sAll'])
reordered_columns = ['feature', 'coef', 'features_mean', 'feature_ith_value','shap_value_true', 'shap_value_python_s100','shap_value_python_sAll','shap_value_abs_diff_s100', 'shap_value_abs_diff_sAll']
results_merged_df = results_merged_df.loc[:,reordered_columns]
print(results_merged_df)
```